# Extern libraries as dependency to local libs

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In a language like C, we deal with three different translation units: object files, libraries, and executables. If I've understood correctly, Rust has skipped the first. That is, if I want to divide my project into several translation units I have to use local crates as shown in this [blog](https://gillesleblanc.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/using-a-local-crate-with-cargo/).

If one uses the extern crate (E) nearly everywhere in code (i.e. my local lib crates and the binary crate), then one has to include E in all `Cargo.toml` dependencies.

Questions:

- Does this mean that E's code is included several times in the final binary?
- If I want to update E's version, I have to change all `Cargo.toml` files. Is there an alternative where I can specify "common" dependencies?
- Is the cited approach idiomatic? While possible, the Rust community seems not to advocate<sup>1</sup> sub-crates beside of in workspaces

I'm aware that using dynamic libraries would be a solution in part; however, my project is an embedded one without support for dynamic libraries.

<sup>1</sup> *This is my personal impression; sorry if I'm wrong here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to divide my project into several translation units

You don't explain **why** you want to do this. If it's for compilation performance reasons, then you might just want to wait for better incremental compilation support. Splitting into crates may or may not help with compilation time based on what kind of code is involved — crates with highly generic APIs will see less benefit, for example.

I'd say that semantic / organizational reasons are the best reason to split things up.

> Does this mean that E's code is included several times in the final binary?

No. When Cargo performs dependency resolution, it attempts to resolve a single version of each dependency. If your dependency tree has conflicting version requirements, then multiple versions might be included, but that's the only way to compile such code anyway. Using a tool like cargo-tree can help you find crates that are forcing multiple versions to be included.

> I have to change all Cargo.toml files.

Your **Cargo.toml** file should not need to be changed *unless* you need to upgrade to a semver incompatible version of a crate. Your **Cargo.lock**, which [only exists for your final binary](http://doc.crates.io/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries) is the only file that needs to be changed.

> Is the cited approach idiomatic? While possible, the Rust community seems not to advocate sub-crates beside of in workspaces

The main downside I see is that you will need to *publish* multiple crates if you wanted to do something like that. If you are just building a binary, I see no reason not to do so. [Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/) is an example of a larger binary project that is composed of many smaller crates.